# numpy.interpd -returning only the last value after interpolation

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, linear-interpolation

I have a set of data points in pressure(p) and vmr.
I want to find the vmr values for another pressure grid(pressure_grid).I used np.interp,

```
for lines in itertools.islice(input_file, i, l):
   lines=lines.split()
   p.append(float(lines[0]))
   vmr.append(float(lines[3]))
   x = np.array(p)
   y = np.array(vmr) 

yi=np.interp(pressure_grid,x,y)
```

But when I tried to print "yi" it is printing only the value(i.e.,vmr value) corresponding to the last value of "pressure_grid".For all iterations it is printing the same value
I tried to print p and vmr ,Everything seems to be fine till there.I'm not able to understand why this is happening...
I'm new to this........Please Help

This is how my file looks like,first column-p and second column-vmr.

[image]

and this is my pressure grid

[image]

https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmPNuP3pNnN8g35NPwIfzSl-VBeO
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmPNuP3pNnN8hAx3opovgipabSjJ

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code?

Comment: Make sure that the pressure_grid values are contained between the minimal and the maximal value of x. Otherwise if the value of pressure_grid are higher than the maximum of x, it will return the y value for the maximum of x

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,pressure_grid values have values that are higher than x,Is there any other way to extrapolate those values.I tried using scipy.interpolate , but it is also not working..can someone suggest any other methods to do this.....      thankyou

Comment: can you post the sample input files in text so I can use them?

Comment: i have added the onedrive links........Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First `x` and `y` are being overwritten for each iteration of the `for` loop, which means, `x` and `y` contain just a single element for the interpolation. To fix this, you could define `x` and `y` list outside the loop and append in the `for` loop, or more simply, just use `numpy.loadtxt()`:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('demo.txt',comments='<',usecols=[0,2])
```

Here, I have specified to skip rows beginning with a less than sign, so we only get the actual data.

Second, for `numpy.interp` to actually work, you need the x-coordinate to be an [increasing sequence](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html). (check the notes). For your data, x is a decreasing sequence, so you should flip the data after loading it:

```
x = data[::-1,0]
y = data[::-1,1]
interpolation = np.interp(grid,x,y)
```

Alternatively, you could just use the `scipy.interpolate` package on the original, unflipped data. This has the added advantage of allowing you to extrapolate data that isn't enclosed by your input domain:

```
from scipy import interpolate
interpolation = interpolate.interp1d(x,y,fill_value='extrapolate')
```

Note: your input file appears to have more than one `<Matrix> </Matrix>` set. To get all this to work, I trimmed the file so it only contained one dataset. Otherwise, your x input data will not be strictly increasing, even after flipping, and you will have to sort.

Comment: Thank you..Thank you so much..scipy.interpolate worked and I got the desired result.